# 21.04 Server help with CPU temperature readings

Tags: temperature, 21.04, lm-sensors

I have installed lm-sensors and when I run the sensor command I get this:

```
enp69s0-pci-4500
Adapter: PCI adapter
PHY Temperature:  +48.0°C  
MAC Temperature:  +48.7°C  

amd_energy-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Ecore000:    160.24 kJ
Ecore001:    161.06 kJ
Ecore002:    165.51 kJ
Ecore003:    160.43 kJ
Ecore004:    163.61 kJ
Ecore005:    166.48 kJ
Ecore006:    160.34 kJ
Ecore007:    163.91 kJ
Ecore008:    164.50 kJ
Ecore009:    159.33 kJ
Ecore010:    160.63 kJ
Ecore011:    166.79 kJ
Ecore012:    171.08 kJ
Ecore013:    171.62 kJ
Ecore014:    177.26 kJ
Ecore015:    172.70 kJ
Ecore016:    175.50 kJ
Ecore017:    179.60 kJ
Ecore018:    164.02 kJ
Ecore019:    167.65 kJ
Ecore020:    167.81 kJ
Ecore021:    164.90 kJ
Ecore022:    169.94 kJ
Ecore023:    174.48 kJ
Esocket0:      9.85 MJ

nvme-pci-2400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +80.8°C)
                       (crit = +80.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nct6797-isa-0a20
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:                     1.38 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                   992.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in2:                     3.39 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in3:                     3.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in4:                   992.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                   152.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                   592.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in7:                     3.39 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in8:                     3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in9:                     1.82 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                  728.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in11:                  528.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                    1.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                  728.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                    1.54 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                  1660 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                  2772 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan7:                  3426 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +42.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = CPU diode
CPUTIN:                 +46.0°C  (high = +112.0°C, hyst = +85.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:                +50.5°C  (high = +112.0°C, hyst = +85.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:                +41.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                +55.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                 -2.0°C    sensor = thermistor
SMBUSMASTER 0:          +74.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C  
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C  
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C  
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled

nvme-pci-4c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +41.9°C  (low  = -60.1°C, high = +89.8°C)
                       (crit = +94.8°C)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +41.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +41.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +64.8°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-2100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +80.8°C)
                       (crit = +80.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +46.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nouveau-pci-4b00
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +41.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +110.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

nvme-pci-4300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +48.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +48.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +64.8°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +73.8°C  
Tdie:         +73.8°C  
Tccd1:        +67.0°C  
Tccd3:        +60.5°C  
Tccd5:        +67.2°C  
Tccd7:        +66.2°C  

nvme-pci-2300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +80.8°C)
                       (crit = +80.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +48.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +43.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +81.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +43.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +61.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

nvme-pci-2200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +80.8°C)
                       (crit = +80.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +48.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

I am unsure which one is my actual CPU temperature(how to decipher temp readings by sensor).  I have a MSI Creator MB with a TR 24/48 CPU.

I would also like to have something (bash?) that watches this temperature and keeps a min/max/24h average but have been unable to find something for this for server installs.

I also installed glances which is nice but if I activate sensors, there are far to many to show.

Linux is not my strong point for sure so I could just be missing something simple
Any help in the right direction would be appreciated